# MySQL SELECT with fields less and greater than values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to do a select query on MySQL with phpMyAdmin or PHP with PDO.

```
SELECT 'uid' FROM 'clusters' WHERE 'lat'<='47.21125' AND 'lat'>='39.21125' AND 'lng'<='32.90243' AND 'lng'>='22.90243'
```

However, phpMyAdmin says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''clusters' WHERE 'lat'<='47.21125' AND 'lat'>='39.21125' AND 'lng'<='32.90243' A' at line 1
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`''` creates a string literal in MySQL, so your query is selecting the literal "uid" from the literal "clusters," which is invalid.  Use backtics (or nothing)

```
SELECT Uid FROM clusters WHERE lat <= 47.21125 AND lat >= 39.21125
AND lng >= 22.90243
```

Comment: i just want to say, is not me who give a down vote. however, you should not using quote for the double value as well.

Comment: @ajreal I don't think that it makes a difference, but I edited my answer to remove them

Comment: the quote will force mysql to perform unnecessary casting, which by no mean ... the index could be ignored (however, the SQL by OP is not using index)

Comment: @ajreal that's only if it's a decimal and not a string.  It's possible that the column is a string, but I think it is more likely that it is a decimal so I changed my answer anyway.  Can you cite the fact that MySQL ignores indices on numeric columns when compared to a string value?

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34384 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43319 .. for both bug, the example are using really BIG numeric number, however, I believe, the core issue is caused by using the "quote" as it mentioned in the details.